# Keycloack jwt configuration - how to hide or omit resource_access of jwt token

Tags: jwt, keycloak

I want to be able to generate a JWT token which does NOT include the `resource_access` property using the simple api login method.

The usecase is that I want to generate an offline token and store it on an nfc chip for long term usage. The `resource_access` however "bloats" up the token since we have lots of different roles.
This causes the reading prozess to take forever.

Answer (score 4):

Try to configure used OIDC client in the Keycloak. Remove `roles` from `Assigned Default Client Scopes`.

Comment: This will remove all roles including realm_access.roles

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

Go to Client Scopes > roles > Mappers > client roles

Then deselect "Add to ID token".

This should ideally remove "resource_access" section from JWT

Comment: This will remove all roles including realm_access.roles